# program Average run not as i expected

Tags: java

When i run program, DecimalFormat not true as i expected.
Example: when i input point 3.2 3.5 4.9, i hope result: 3.8
but it:3.8666667143503823.
When i input point 2 2 2, result: 2.0 
Why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Nhập vào điểm môn chuyen can :");
        double diemChuyenCan = scanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Nhập vào điểm kiểm tra: ");
        double diemKiemTra = scanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Nhập vào điểm học kỳ: ");
        double diemHocKy = scanner.nextFloat();

        DecimalFormat dcf = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
         double diemMonHoc = (diemChuyenCan + diemKiemTra + diemHocKy) /3;
         dcf.format(diemMonHoc);
        if(diemMonHoc>=8) {

            System.out.println("Điểm trung bình là: "+ diemMonHoc + " Môn 
        học giỏi");
        }else if(diemMonHoc >= 6.5 && diemMonHoc < 8){

            System.out.println(" Môn học  khá");
        }else if( diemMonHoc >= 5 && diemMonHoc < 6.5) {

            System.out.println(diemMonHoc +" Môn học trung bình");
        }else {

            System.out.println(diemMonHoc +" Môn học kém");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the logic of your code (don't understand the lingo)

```
DecimalFormat dcf = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
double diemMonHoc = (diemChuyenCan + diemKiemTra + diemHocKy) /3;

// format returns a String, so use that
String formattedDate = dcf.format(diemMonHoc);
System.out.println (formattedDate );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you were using the double type when printing your output
not the formatted one.
In this code you can round your output:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Nhập vào điểm môn chuyen can :");
    double diemChuyenCan = scanner.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Nhập vào điểm kiểm tra: ");
    double diemKiemTra = scanner.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Nhập vào điểm học kỳ: ");
    double diemHocKy = scanner.nextFloat();

    DecimalFormat dcf = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    double diemMonHoc = (diemChuyenCan + diemKiemTra + diemHocKy) /3;
    dcf.format(diemMonHoc);
    if(diemMonHoc>=8) {

        System.out.println("Điểm trung bình là: "+ dcf.format(diemMonHoc) + " Mônhọc giỏi");
    }else if(diemMonHoc >= 6.5 && diemMonHoc < 8){

        System.out.println(" Môn học  khá");
    }else if( diemMonHoc >= 5 && diemMonHoc < 6.5) {

        System.out.println(dcf.format(diemMonHoc) +" Môn học trung bình");
    }else {

        System.out.println(dcf.format(diemMonHoc) +" Môn học kém");
    }
}
```

But in the above code it rounds the number and the output for these inputs:3.2 3.5 4.9
is 3.9 and if you don't want to round it you should to use this format "#.##" so the output will be 3.87.

Have a Good day.

Comment: why have `dcf.format(diemMonHoc);` and then do it in each of your `print` statements?

Comment: BTW you can also put dcf.format(diemMonHoc) in a String and 
replace others with that Strng.